# Google sheets: match by two rows and extract to different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am building a reporting sheet that automatically extracts hours worked by person, date, and project from an aggregated sheet and transposes the data horizontally to a different spreadsheet.
The `origin` sheet looks like this: [image: origin sheet]

The `target` sheet looks like this for each employee: [image: target sheet]

I am trying to figure out a function that extracts the relevant data from `origin` based on the name, project, and month values contained in row 2 of the `target` sheet. The origin sheet lists several more employees horizontally and several years vertically. I know I need the `importrange` function, but I am struggling with finding an extraction function based on the name, project, and day.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this series of formulas:

#### Output (D7):

```
=transpose(query({Sheet1!C3:C,indirect("Sheet1!"&address(3, Y3, 4)&":"&left(address(3, Y3, 4), 1))}, 
           "select Col2 where 
                   Col1 > date '"&text(date(C2, month(A2&1),), "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and 
                   Col1 < date '"&text(date(C2, month(A2&1) + 1, 1), "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"))
```

I also added some formulas in other cells that are needed by the output, these are:

```
Y1 = match(L2, Sheet1!A1:1)

Y2 = if(L2 = query(transpose(Sheet1!1:1), "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc limit 1"), 
        counta(Sheet1!1:1)+countblank(Sheet1!1:1), 
        match(regexextract(join(",", Sheet1!1:1), L2&",*([^,]*),"), Sheet1!1:1))

Y3 = Y1 + match(P2, indirect("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(2, Y1 + 1, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(2, Y2 - 1, 4)))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]